# d3 slider library on simple data set

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I found this slider library promising at the onset, but I have been having immense difficulty in adapting it to a simplified data set. [this block](https://bl.ocks.org/johnwalley/e1d256b81e51da68f7feb632a53c3518) has the slider in action. I'm trying to replicate the "New York Times" variety. And below is my snippet with a teeny tiny hardcoded data set.

```js
var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:100, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 1200;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

var data = [
  {'manager':'ABC-CA', 'aum':230561804112.86996},
  {'manager':'AEGON-Industrial', 'aum':187676730861.82004},
  {'manager':'AVIC', 'aum':677643221.8599999},
  {'manager':'AXA-SPDB', 'aum':111220010833.66998},
  {'manager':'Baoying', 'aum':26328526612.41},
  {'manager':'Beixin Ruifeng', 'aum':10500065729.3},
  {'manager':'BOB-Scotiabank', 'aum':69159188249.67},
  {'manager':'BOC IM', 'aum':396466612963.73},
  {'manager':'BOCI Securities', 'aum':57940275708.97}
];

  var yExtents = d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.aum; })

  var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.manager; }));

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([height,0])
      .domain(yExtents);

  graphGroup.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 0 + ")")
      .call(d3.axisRight(yScale))
      .selectAll("text")
      .attr('text-align','right')
      .attr("transform", "translate(-90,0)");

  graphGroup.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
      .selectAll("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");

  var bars = graphGroup.append('g')
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(data);

  var barsEnter = bars
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('x', function(d) {return xScale(d.manager); })
      .attr('y', function(d) {return yScale(d.aum); })
      .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
      .attr('height', function(d) {return height-yScale(d.aum); });

      var slider = g =>
        g.attr('transform', `translate(0,0)`).call(
          d3
            .sliderBottom(xScale)
            .step(1)
            .ticks(4)
            .default(9)
            .on('onchange', value => draw(value))
        );

        graphGroup.append('g').call(slider);

        var draw = selected => {
          barsEnter
            .merge(bars)
            .attr('fill', d => (d.manager === selected ? '#003366' : '#e0e0e0'));

          d3.select('p#value-new-york-times').text(
            d3.format('$,.2r')(data[selected - 1].value)
          );
        };

        draw(9);
```

```html
<div class="row align-items-center">
  <div class="col-sm-2"><p id="value-new-york-times"></p></div>
  <div class="col-sm"><div id="slider-new-york-times"></div></div>
</div>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-simple-slider"></script>
```

The script crashes citing d3-simple-slider @ line 2:

> TypeError: h.clamp is not a function

It runs fine in the example, but it crashes on my data set. I have virtually the exact same implementation, all that is different is the data set and the svg container. To my knowledge, these discrepancies shouldn't be deal-breakers.

### Question

Could anybody within the d3 community that has experience with this particular library offer some insight as to why the script is crashing?

Comment: What you are looking to implement (from the link) is a slider. A slider does not take string input, that's why your code is falling over with your data set. Your data set is of the incorrect format. If you just want to make an x/y line/circle graph etc, don't use the slider d3, just use the d3 library. The code for that is different. Have a look at the code for [this scatter graph](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/ynx4sxy8/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/s9kt6fvg/ NY slider (data should have range/year/value format) It's not the dataset size, it's the format that's the 'dealbreaker'